# Fix HTML closing tag issue while using parse-xml-fragment

Tags: xslt-3.0

Is there any way to fix HTML Markup in XSLT 3.0 like `Beautifulsoup` in `python` and `tagsoup` in `java`.

When I try to read text with `parse-xml-fragment` it gave error for unclosed `<br>`

Comment: Commercial versions of Saxon (i.e. PE and EE) for older releases have an extension function `saxon:parse-html`, current releases have experimental `fn:parse-html` support if you switch to `version="4.0"`. In the context of Python I think SaxonC 12.3 PE and EE should support `fn:parse-html` in XSLT 4.0 stylesheets.

Comment: Inside the browser with SaxonJS 2 you could probably get away with calling into JavaScript and use `new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html')`. In other settings you could use the TagSoup parser implementation David Carlisle has done in XSLT 2.

Answer (score 3):

Examples for doing it with Python 3 and SaxonC HE, importing (a modified version of) David Carlisle's HTML tag soup parser in XSLT 2 is at https://github.com/martin-honnen/SaxonCUseXSLTHTMLParser.

It has a stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:dc="data:,dpc"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:param name="json-uri" as="xs:string" select="'input-sample1.json'"/>

  <xsl:import href="htmlparse.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json-doc($json-uri)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=".">
    <Root>
      <process>{?process}</process>
      <title>{?title}</title>
      <content>
        <xsl:sequence select="dc:htmlparse(?content, '', true())" />
      </content>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that, when run with the initial template or with a JSON input document `input-sample1.json` of the form

```
{
"process": "Test",
"title": "Json2XML_Conversion",
"content": "<div id=contents><p class=Head>This need to process as title<p class=para>This is line 1.<br>This is line 2.<br>This is line 3.</div>"
}
```

creates the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <process>Test</process>
   <title>Json2XML_Conversion</title>
   <content>
      <div id="contents">
         <p class="Head">This need to process as title</p>
         <p class="para">This is line 1.<br/>This is line 2.<br/>This is line 3.</p>
      </div>
   </content>
</Root>
```

Python3 code to run SaxonC HE 12.3 is e.g.

```
from saxonche import *

with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as saxon_processor:

    print(saxon_processor.version)

    xslt_proc = saxon_processor.new_xslt30_processor()

    xslt_executable = xslt_proc.compile_stylesheet(stylesheet_file='import-htmlparse-test1.xsl')

    result = xslt_executable.call_template_returning_string()

    print(result)
```

Of course the XSLT should work with any current Saxon Java, Saxon C, SaxonCS, SaxonJS or other XSLT 3.0 processors.

Answer (score 0):

If the problems are limited and without ambiguity, you can try simple text substitution.

In this example, there is a `<br>` html element without an XML closing tag.

```
{
"process": "Test",
"title": "Json2XML_Conversion",
"content": "<div id=\"contents\"><p class=\"Head\">First line<br>Second line</p></div>"
}
```

You can use `replace()` to make it into a self-closing tag.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  expand-text="yes"
  version="3.0">
  
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match=".">
        <Root>
          <process>{.?process}</process>
          <title>{.?title}</title>
          <content>
            <xsl:sequence select="parse-xml-fragment(.?content => replace('br>', 'br/>'))" />
          </content>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```